# Dynamically insert data into a temp table with like as variable

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to dynamically insert data into a temp table passing like data as a variable:

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @data = 'INSERT INTO #coco  ' + '([' + @val + '])' + ' SELECT [USER_ID] FROM [dbo].[Sheet1$] WHERE [Standard_Name] LIKE ' + @val

EXEC sp_executesql @data
```

`@val` is a column name selected from table `Sheet1$` and few column name has space between them. While executing, I am getting error, like for column name "Acrobat Reader":

> Incorrect syntax near 'Acrobat'.

Also if I am adding data using hardcoded one by one in a column its adding data to one column while other column its adding NULL.

Any suggestion how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Parametrise your SQL, and this problem "goes away":

```
DECLARE @data;
SET @data = N'INSERT INTO #Coco (' QUOTENAME(@val) + N')' + NCHAR(10) + 
            N'SELECT [USER_ID]' + NCHAR(10) + 
            N'FROM dbo.[Sheet1$]' + NCHAR(10) + 
            N'WHERE [Standard_Name] = @val;'; --As this doesn't contain a %, there's no need for LIKE
EXEC sp_executesql @data,
                   N'@val = sysname', --guessed datatype
                   @val = @val;
```

Note the comments I made in the SQL though.

Afraid, I've no idea what your second statement means. You'll need to explain further.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, trying your suggestion.
For second question, I am selecting all value of a Table column based on Column Name and then trying to insert them in a temp table. For each column i am doing a loop. So,in loop when values are inserted for one column, other column values are set to Null automatically, and when other column data is being inserted it starts inserting value from end of 1st column value. Is there a way i can add values for each column from beginning.

Comment: Comments aren't the place for explanations, put them in your question. Sample Data and Expected results will likely greatly help.